# Error when attempting to use shapefile ImageMosaic store as basis for layer

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to serve up a large number of TIF files and worldfiles through GeoServer, as an ImageMosaic store. I've followed the steps in the ImageMosaic tutorial as described here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html - I've pointed GeoServer at a shapefile containing the locations of the TIF files, and the shapefile is accompanied by a .prj file for the correct projection (EPSG:4326) and a .properties file that as far as I'm aware contains the correct information.
The TIF files are on another server, but the location has been added as a network drive on the GeoServer machine and the paths in the shapefile for each tile are correct.

However, when I attempt to use this store as the basis for a layer, I get the following error report (with substitutions for actual paths). The part that looks important is towards the end, where it says it's having problems visiting the directory where the imagery is stored, and after that where it says the location of the imagery is an illegal argument.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while building the resources for the configuration page 
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:356) 
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$8.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:281)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:46)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:68)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:177)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:300)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.BehaviorRequestTarget.processEvents(BehaviorRequestTarget.java:119)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450) 
Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to create this mosaic
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:1390)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.processRequest(RasterLayerResponse.java:1228)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.createResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:1194)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.read(RasterManager.java:1143)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:863)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.read(ImageMosaicReader.java:842)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:227)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:141)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:968)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:856)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:346) 
    ... 97 more 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem visiting IMAGE_DIRECTORY visiting IMAGE_DIRECTORY.25516:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument: "granuleLocation=Z:\IMAGE_PATH\IMAGE.TIF".
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.accepts(ContentFeatureSource.java:768)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.accepts(ContentFeatureCollection.java:120)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.getGranuleDescriptors(CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.java:158)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterManager.getGranuleDescriptors(RasterManager.java:1153)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.RasterLayerResponse.prepareResponse(RasterLayerResponse.java:1339) 
    ... 107 more 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument: "granuleLocation=Z:\IMAGE_PATH\IMAGE.TIF".
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.GranuleDescriptor.<init>(GranuleDescriptor.java:607)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog.CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog$1.visit(CachingDataStoreGranuleCatalog.java:175)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.accepts(ContentFeatureSource.java:759) 
    ... 111 more
```

Can GeoServer not access items on network drives (without extra work) or is something else probably going on here?

Comment: it's hard to tell without knowing the actual image path - does it contain spaces? other odd characters? I'm guessing you are on windows so it might be a backslash issue - try changing to / or doubling them to \\